# How to collapse multiple rows into one and create series of column elements Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, jupyter-notebook, series

I have a dataframe such as one below:

```
                tags    categories            classification
          0    label    ['legislative', 
                         'law, govt and 
                         politics', 'exe...        None
          0   document  ['legislative', 
                         'law, govt and politics', 
                            'exe...                 NaN
          0     text    ['legislative', 'law, 
                          govt and politics', 
                          'exe...                   NaN
          0     paper   ['legislative', 'law, 
                          govt and 
                        politics', 'exe...          NaN
          0     poster  ['legislative', 'law, 
                        govt and politics', 'exe... NaN
```

I want to create a new dataframe where I can collapse the above dataframe into one below such that the column elements of the columns 'tags' and 'classification' are converted into single rows with individual items in list format such as

```
                tags     categories           classification
       0   ['label',     ['legislative',      ['None','NaN',
           'document',  'law, govt and          'NaN','NaN',
             'text',          politics', 'exe...    'NaN']                
         'paper',poster']
```

How do I go about doing this? How could I use stack or group by functions on this to obtain the result? Thanks in advance.

*Here's the result to df.to_dict()

```
           {'tags': {0: ' letter',
            1: ' head',
            2: ' water',
            3: ' art',
            4: ' indoors',
            5: ' flyer',
            6: ' poster',
            ...},
            'categories': {0: "['legislative', 'law, govt and politics', 
            'executive branch', 'work', 'society', 'government']",
            1: "['unrest and war', 'society', 'religion and spirituality', 
            'buddhism']",
            2: '[]',
            3: '[]',
            4: "['unemployment', 'society', 'law, govt and politics', 
            'foreign policy', 'work', 'politics', 'armed forces']",
            5: '[]',
            6: "['sports', 'law, govt and politics', 'wrestling']",
            ...},
            'classfication': {0: nan,
            1: nan,
            2: nan,
            3: nan,
            4: nan,
            5: nan,
            6: nan,
            ...}}
```

Comment: Can You paste result of: `df.to_dict()`, where `df` is Your dataframe please?

Comment: Could you be more clear? I couldn't understand your task thoroughly. I think you also want to collapse `classification` column, right?

Comment: @ipj I've  pasted the result

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question completely. But do you want something like this?

**df:**

```
    trial_num   subject samples
0   1           1       [-1.74, -0.78, -0.11]
1   2           1       [0.86, 0.21, -0.01]
2   3           1       [2.04, 0.6, -0.79]
3   1           2       [0.52, 0.49, 1.56]
4   2           2       [0.07, 0.84, -1.1]
5   3           2       [0.43, -1.3, 1.99]
```

**converted df:**

```
     trial_num          subject             samples
0   [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]  [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]  [[-1.74, -0.78, -0.11], [0.86, 0.21, -0.0...trial_num   subject samples
0   [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]  [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]  [[-1.74, -0.78, -0.11], [0.86, 0.21, -0.0...
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'trial_num': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
     'subject': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
     'samples': [list(np.random.randn(3).round(2)) for i in range(6)]
    }
)
df = df.astype(str).apply(', '.join).apply(lambda x: x.split(',')).to_frame().T
```